# choose labels to show inside legend of jqplot

Tags: limit, jqplot, label, series

the jqPlot displays labels of ALL the series it has on the graph. I want to show only some of the series on the labels. The thing is that some of lines are just there to show proper limit for values (visually) - some points are above, some below. For now I simply put empty string for labels, but the label point in the label area is  still there - it doesn't look good.

Here is the code:

```
        series:[
          {lineWidth:1, color: '#d8d8d8', showMarker: false},
          {lineWidth:0.5, color: 'red', showMarker: false},
          {lineWidth:1, color: '#d8d8d8', showMarker: false},
          {lineWidth:1, color: '#d8d8d8', showMarker: false},
          {lineWidth:1, color: '#76a4e8', showMarker: false},
          {lineWidth:1, color: '#d8d8d8', showMarker: false},
          {lineWidth:0.5, color: 'red', showMarker: false},
          {lineWidth:1, color: '#d8d8d8', showMarker: false},                                                            
          {lineWidth:1, color: '#d8d8d8', showMarker: false},
          {
            lineWidth:0.5, 
            color: 'green', 
            rendererOptions: {animation: {speed: 1500}}, 
            markerOptions:{color: 'green', 
            style:'filledSquare'},            
          },
          //here are the series with real values - they come from php in red or orange
        ],
        legend:{
           renderer: jQuery.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,
           show: true,
           hideZeros: true,
           location: 'e',
//labele with names           
//labels: [ 'SD+4', 'SD+3', 'SD+2', 'SD+1','Perfect value', 'SD-1', 'SD-2', 'SD-3', 'SD-4', 'Real Values', 'Vales to high'],
//labele with empty points
labels: [ ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ','Perfect value', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'Real Values', 'Vales to high'],
placement: 'outsideGrid'
        }
```

[image]

As you see it doesn't look too good. Only Perfect value, real values, and values too high/low should be shown.